# Differences in std::tm tm_wday behavior between GCC 9.4 and GCC 12.1

Tags: c++, datetime, ubuntu, gcc

I use a docker container for my C++ application and I use the ubuntu:20 image as a bas image to create a debug environment. I recently decided to upgrade the base image.So I migrated my OS from Ubuntu 20 to Ubuntu 22, and in the process, upgraded GCC from 9.4 to 12.1. After this upgrade, I noticed a discrepancy in the behavior of my application related to the week day extraction from a std::tm structure.

In my code, I parse a date-time string into a std::tm object using std::get_time. When I used GCC 9.4, the tm_wday was being set to 0 for Monday, but after upgrading to GCC 12.1, it sets tm_wday to 1 for Monday. In the [standards](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm), the range [0-6] (days since Sunday) is used for the day of the week (tm_wday). Accordingly, GCC 12.x works correctly because the date I gave points on Monday. I read all the changelogs between the two versions of GCC, but I couldn't find any information about this issue. This made me suspicious.

Here's the relevant snippet of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

int main() {
    std::string input = "2019-02-18 22:10:10";
    std::tm timeinfo = {};

    std::istringstream ss(input);
    ss >> std::get_time(&timeinfo, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

    if (ss.fail()) {
        std::cout << "Failed to parse time." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    } else {
        // Display tm_wday value without using mktime
        std::cout << "Without mktime:" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "tm_wday: " << timeinfo.tm_wday << std::endl;

        // Use mktime to normalize the timeinfo structure.
        std::mktime(&timeinfo);

        // Display tm_wday value after using mktime
        std::cout << "\nWith mktime:" << std::endl;
        std::string weekdays[] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
        std::cout << "tm_wday: " << weekdays[timeinfo.tm_wday] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm curious if anyone else has noticed a change in behavior with std::tm between these GCC versions, or if there's something else at play here. I've checked the GCC changes but couldn't find anything relevant. You can use this [link](https://godbolt.org/z/neGW46v6h) for test purpose

Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked the `tm_isdst` flag? It could affect things. How about time-zones? Perhaps it could also affect things. Also check the date to see if it's changed.

Comment: It sounds like a locale difference rather than a language or standard library difference.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77760

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your suggestions. I used https://godbolt.org/ to test the code. Here I can select the GCC version. I can see the difference with the same code, same timezone. @AlanBirtles you are amazing, it was exactly what I was looking for.I appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that it's [unspecified](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time) whether `std::get_time` sets fields that aren't in the format string. Libc++ and MSVC's standard library also don't set `tm_wday` in your code.

There is a [gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77760) to fix this but it hasn't been resolved. I'd guess it's been "fixed" accidentally  by other library changes.

If you want all the fields of `std::tm` to be set you should always call `std::mktime`. Note that you [should set `tm_isdst`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime) before calling `std::mktime` as `std::get_time` doesn't set it for you.